# How to continous run a function although view controller is dismiss or app is closed swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to upload a photo,video and audio via Alamofire. But it takes some time to complete the upload,so I dont want to freeze the UI,but when users go to another screen,my server cant get the image.So I want the upload function is run continuously although user go to another screen or even user is closed the app.

I tried the this, but I not sure right or not :

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    uploadToServer(myImage)
}

func uploadToServer() {
  let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["authorization":apiKey]
  let params :[ String : Any ] = ["imageBase64String" :"image"]
  let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 600

    manager.request(AppConfig.my_url!, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let result):
            let json = JSON(result)
            let error = json["error"]
            print("error=\(error)")
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }
}
```

I want to make sure the content is 100% send to server even the app is close,so the data wont be lost.

So how to do this??

Comment: Mind that if user will kill app, he will kill all tasks as well. You can't prevent it. However you try to cache the data and try to upload it on next launch.

Comment: what does your `uploadToServer(_:)` code look like?

Comment: @staticVoidMan is Alamofire code

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov what if run the function although user go to another screen?

Comment: @ken Show sanitized code none-the-less. Just for a better idea. There's just one small thing you need to do but I want to be sure what you're doing inside.

Comment: If you call anything in DispatchQueue block, it will be executed. You have to be particularly careful about referring your viewController, because you can create Retain Cycles (https://medium.com/mackmobile/avoiding-retain-cycles-in-swift-7b08d50fe3ef).

Comment: @ken have you tried this? it should technically work as async blocks execute their task even if the `viewController` it was called in is deallocated. Although, one obvious thing I see incorrect is that it should be `self.uploadToServer(myImage)`

Comment: @staticVoidMan I tried,but the image is sent after 5 minutes..is anything wrong about this?

Comment: @ken Well you are sending the image as a base64 string in the payload & that data can be pretty big. Plus your network speed can slow the process.

Comment: @staticVoidMan and one more thing,I figure out that,when the background function is being call,all other function which not in background is request timed out..can I know why??

Comment: @ken Your other calls being timed out will be due to some other problem. Not here atleast

Comment: @ken Btw, I would send image as multipart. Base 64 bloats the request by 33% more data. So with a multipart upload, you could reduce your time to upload.

Comment: @staticVoidMan thanks for suggestion..